# int cannot be deferenced java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am new to java, and I have a problem that I just have no idea how to fix. I've been searching here on stackoverflow and on other sites and I am just so confused.

I am just trying to copy my l array to a new array that's called A...

Here is my code:

```
public class Problem3 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int l[] = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
        ArrayTools.print();

        ArrayTools.createIntArray();
        //hämta class ArrayTools och alla metoder

    }
}


class ArrayTools {

    public static void print (){
 System.out.println ("ArrayTools");
    }

    public int [] createIntArray (int l){

        int [] A = l.clone();

        System.out.println(A);
        return A;

        }
  }
```

And what I get is a "int cannot be dereferenced" error when I try to compile my code.

And also I get another error with the ArrayTools.createIntArray, but I will figure that out later.

Comment: `l` is an `int`, not an array

Comment: Please change the type of the parameter l from int to int[].

Comment: You main method calling ArrayTools.createIntArray() without any parameter. And your method declaration itself createIntArray(int l) also wrong. I believed your parameter should be an array instead of int.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the type of the parameter l from int to int[].

Comment: Oh, wow, that was what I was missing haha! Thank you!